# Understanding memory structure when casting pointers of different sizes of structs

Tags: c

```
struct A //size 4
struct B //size 8

unsigned char *mem; 
A *a=(A *)mem; 
B *b=(B *)a+sizeof(A); //I want address of b to be 4
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong:

lets say address of `mem` is `0`, if so

address of `a` is `0`, if so

address of `b` is `0+8*4 //0+sizeof(A)*sizeof(B)`

If that's correct
How I cast 'pointer to struct A' to 'pointer to struct B' then add to the address a number. (commented in the code)

Thanks.

Comment: Recommended reading: [what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that if `p` is of type `T*`, then the address `p+n` is the address `p` plus `n*sizeof(T)`.

If `pa` is of type `A*` to cast it to type `B*` you simply write `B * pb = (B*)pa;`.

If you want to advance it by a given number of bytes `n`, you can cast to `char*` first, advance (since `sizeof(char)=1`), and then cast of to `B*`. I.e., `B* pb = (B*)( ((char*)pa) +n);`

However, except for very special circumstances, you shouldn't really need to do something like this, since it is very easy to get garbage as a result.

Whatever it is that you are actually trying to do, there is probably a better and less error prone way.

Comment: I'm actually trying to parse a binary file, so I need to get to some position then cast it to some struct then get to other position then cast it to different struct. Is there a way that can do that better?

Comment: It would be preferable to just have `char *` pointer that you advance and cast to the different struct pointer types as required, as opposed to converting between different struct pointers. I admit that does not gain you a whole bunch, but I would argue it is a bit cleaner.

Comment: @Neet33 Also, if the layout of your binary file is fixed in advance (i.e., always two struct As, followed by a struct B, etc), you could just define a bigger packed struct that contains these structs and read into that. You can then let the compiler do all of the addressing for you.

Comment: Are you aware of the strict aliasing rule? You are just violating it.

Comment: You mean the answer poster is violating it?